# Selecting content of a html textarea using jquery _nearly_ works, except

Tags: jquery, firefox, select

In a web application I want to fire a dialog using jquery. The dialog serves to offer a string to be copied to the clipboard by the user (Ctrl-C). To make things simple I want to select (highlight) that string which is specified as the value of a textarea. In addition I bind the click handler to selecting the content too, so that the user does not unselect the content when clicking.

However using Firefox (FF 13.0.1/Linux) this does not work. The dialog fires, the textarea accepts the content. The binding works fine. Just the selection of the content simply won't work, except after an explicit click.

So I created a simple use case: 
http://jsfiddle.net/4CK7Y/2/

It contains this code:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <textarea id="payload"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

JS/JQuery:

```
$('#payload').val("some text");
$('#payload').select();
$('#payload').click(function(){this.select();});
```

I was very surprised to see that this works fine in most browsers: Konqueror, Rekonq, Opera. 
However in Firefox this only works upon a fresh reload. If you click on "Run" you see the problem: although the code is re-executed the content of the textarea is NOT selected without being clicked.

What is the cause of this ? What can I do about that ?

Comment: Can you include the code in your question so the question can be preserved for future generations to learn from? (links go away over time)

Answer (score 0):

Because the textarea doesn't get the **focus** automatically on page-load. Attach the **focus()** event to the textarea under **$(document).ready()**.

Comment: The select() does _not_ give focus to the textarea ?

Comment: Ok, I tried to set the focus on the textarea, but I cannot get the desired effect. Setting the focus in a $(document).ready() function does not work for me.
Also: I would expect the "Run" button to re-execute the script. So that adding a focus() in there should work to. But it won't as well. In the original scenario I cannot use a $(document).ready() function, since the dialog is fired from within a running function.

Comment: If you use just **focus()**, only the cursor will be placed at the end of the text within the textarea after the event is fired. If you want it to be focussed with all the text selected, you have to use methods like **setSelectionRange()**...

Comment: All examples and tutorials use select() to select the text contained inside a textarea or text input field. Typically by calling select on the element after a clicked or focus event has been raised. 

In my example the select() also works as expected (selecting all the text contained in the textarea) when the element is clicked. 

Whilst it is true that calling focus() alone does _not_ select the content I do not understand why you claim that I cannot use select() for this.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that **select()** can be used to select text inside textarea. Thanks. Then I really have no idea where the problem is. As per the specs, **select()** should select the text on page-load without any need for **focus()**.